# How to properly use GROUP BY on the result of a Sybase sql subquery

Tags: sql, sybase

I have two separate queries against the same db table which I have returning in the same result set using UNION. Where I am stuck is that I now want to run a GROUP BY on the result as well and I am having no success. Currently there is grouping happening within each UNION (which is good!) by "name_of_asset" but I get two lines for each "name_of_asset" in the final result - one for each inner select. So while the rest of the query is ok the final GROUP BY in the below is not accomplishing what I am trying to do. In fact I don't see it having any effect on my data I just included it below to highlight what I have tried already.

Please note that I am trying to accomplish the following **without** using temp tables.

```
SELECT TOP 4 asset, name_of_asset, usd_today, usd_prev
FROM
(
SELECT 'Asset' asset, name_of_asset, SUM(usd)/1000 usd_today, 0 usd_prev
FROM my_db..my_table
WHERE the_date = '9/30/2014' 
AND asset = 'A'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Asset' asset, name_of_asset, 0 usd_today, SUM(usd)/1000 usd_prev
FROM my_db..my_table
WHERE the_date = '8/29/2014' 
AND asset = 'A'
) x

GROUP BY x.name_of_asset
ORDER BY x.usd_notional DESC
```

*Also before you comment on it please note that for the post I changed all db, table, and column names so no I am not actually working with a table called "my_table" in db "my_db" ...give me some credit my naming convention skills are *slightly* better than that ;p

Thanks in advance for your help! This is my first posted question... edits and constructive criticism always welcome :)

Comment: Other than the GROUP BY's in the subquery being redundant (but harmless), what is not working with the SQL you posted? It looks fine to me. It would be recommended to remove the TOP expressions from the subquery in order to make the outer TOP more predictable.

Comment: So the SQL is "working" ie no fails so it is fine in that sense BUT it is not returning the result I am hoping for. I am getting returned multiple (two) rows per each name_of_asset when I am hoping to GROUP BY name_of_asset and so have a single line in the result set per each distinct name_of_asset. Thank you for your other advice I am editing to reflect that now :)

Comment: These suggestions in combination with the answer below are what I needed. Thanks @Pieter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't group in the union statements.  Like this:

```
SELECT TOP 4 asset, name_of_asset, SUM(usd_today)/1000 usd_today,SUM(usd_prev)/1000 usd_prev
FROM
(
  SELECT 'Asset' asset, name_of_asset, usd usd_today, 0 usd_prev
  FROM my_db..my_table
  WHERE the_date = '9/30/2014' 
  AND asset = 'A'

UNION ALL

  SELECT 'Asset' asset, name_of_asset, 0 usd_today, usd usd_prev
  FROM my_db..my_table
  WHERE the_date = '8/29/2014' 
  AND asset = 'A'
) x
GROUP BY (x.name_of_asset)
```

Note, because you are using sum this can be moved out without problem.  AVG would be an issue but you are not using that agragate.

Comment: Not using the inner GROUP BY statements and using SUM in the outer SELECT is exactly what I needed combined with getting rid of the inner TOP 2s. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ah yes... the top 2s... didn't see that.  they should be out.